# Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): In PHP

Tags: php, audio, upload, wamp

I am trying to upload an audio to server using php. I am getting this error. I understood the problem is due to timeout. But how to change on thew server??

Answer (score 2):

[`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

This will set the time limit to nothing (aka no time limit)

Comment: I am still getting that error
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#54765
This link says this function has no effect on my use case